# Android 1.5-specific error

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having trouble with with getting my application to function on android 1.5. It works fine in 1.6, 2.1, and 2.2 but whenever I attempt to run it in 1.5, I get an immediate force close with the LogCat output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.qrohlf.activites/com.qrohlf.activites.BookmarkHistoryTabActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class
java.lang.reflect.Constructor
```

This strikes me as very odd, as line #2 of my layout XML is just

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Any ideas? Is there some major API change between 1.5 and 1.6 in the way layout XMLs are done that I'm missing?
(I've included the rest of my layout xml below for reference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/custom_titlebar" layout="@layout/custom_titlebar" />
    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/frame_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ListView android:id="@+id/soccerteams_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <ListView android:id="@+id/countries_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    </ViewFlipper>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="0px">
        <Button android:id="@+id/bookmarks_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bookmarks"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_bookmark_tab" 
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/history_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/history"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_history_tab" 
            android:background="@drawable/tab_background"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I think the problem must be in the include <include android:id="@+id/custom_titlebar" layout="@layout/custom_titlebar" />, post that layout too =), but as Romain said post the Stack Trace :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure you have al required drawables in "drawable" directory. 1.5 doesn't understand "drawable-hdpi" directory and others, it only knows "drawable".

Comment: Thanks - figured it out myself after some futzing, but that was the problem.